# How can I pass kwargs to class function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't have much experience with class inheritance. I understand that you can pass any variable to class instance via *args and **kwargs which help one to accommodate child classes.

In the example bellow, I'd like to pass the title, theme and size when instantiating a class which would do for me: `self.title('App')` and `self.set_theme('radiance')`. Now I'm just replacing the attributes, i.e., `self.title = 'App'` and `self.set_theme = 'radiance'` which doesn't do what I want...

```
class App(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

dic = {
    'title': 'App',
    'set_theme': 'radiance',
}
app = App(**dic)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wish the ThemedTK __init__ accepted those arguments but no... My temporary fix is: self.title(kwargs.pop('title'))
        self.set_theme(kwargs.pop('set_theme'))
        self.geometry(kwargs.pop('geometry'))
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```py
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class App(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        title=kwargs.pop('title','')
        theme=kwargs.pop('set_theme',None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title(title)
        if theme:
            self.set_theme(theme)

dic = {
    'title': 'App',
    'set_theme': 'radiance',
}
app = App(**dic)
app.mainloop()
```

You can `pop` (`kwargs.pop(key, default)`) out the `kwargs` that don't go into the `__init__` function of `ThemedTk` in the begining and then pass them into the respective methods later on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AST's answer:

```py
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class App(ThemedTk):
    # The default value for `title` is "Tk" and
    # the default value for `theme` is `None`
    def __init__(self, title="Tk", theme=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title(title)
        # If the theme is None just skip it
        if theme is not None:
            self.set_theme(theme)

dic = {
    'title': 'App',
    'set_theme': 'radiance',
}
app = App(**dic)
app.mainloop()
```